# Loop over a set $\mu_i$

Tags: statistics

I have a set of $\mu_i$ where all the elements are equal, but the following statement is too large for me (I just don't like it):

$$\mu_1=\mu_2=\mu_3=\mu_4=\mu_5=\mu_6$$

So I want to know if there exists a mathematical expression that lets state the previous without having to rewrite the $\mu_i$ every time the $=$ is present. I can think of it like a sum:

$$\sum_{i=1}^6 \mu_i=\mu_{i+1}$$

...but the thing is that the statement is not a sum, and it doesn't seem very clear.

Or maybe something like:

$$allElementsAreEqual(\mu_i)$$

where "$allElementsAreEqual$" is some mathematical expression or kind of.

I hope I explained myself well.

Comment: $\mu_i=\mu_1$ for $1 \leq i \leq 6$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy thanks, do you know a simpler form?

Comment: Do you like $\mu_i=\mu_1 \forall i$?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy nice, does it matter if the limit (6) is not specified?

Comment: Define $\bar \mu = \frac 1n \sum_{i=1}^n \mu_i$ and $\theta = \sum_{i=1}^n (\mu_i - \bar \mu)^2.$ Then your statement that all $\mu_1$ are equal (often $H_0$ for an ANOVA) amounts to $\theta = 0$ and the negation that $\mu_i$ are not all equal (often $H_a$) amounts to $\theta > 0.$ Several intermediate-level statistics books use similar notations.